# rpm -e did not removed installed directory

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

All,

I created a RPM package using rpm.spec file. The package installed succesfully. When i remove the package using rpm -e it removed from RPM database

But directory structure that the pkg created was not removed.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Show the `%files` section of your spec file, without this we can't help you

Comment: it is empty. i did not specify anything

Comment: Eh? An empty `%files` section means your RPM contains no files! OK, paste the entire spec file.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here is what i have

Comment: Can you pastebin your spec file, please? It will be easier

Comment: fde, some extend i altered. Please find if you can read.

Comment: Neither -- believe me, a pastebin will be easier here, or a gist if you are on github

Comment: added fde. thanks for pointing this featue. I did not aware this before

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your spec file:

- your `%files` section is empty, your RPM contains no files at all (try and `rpm -ql packagename`);
- you do all of your work in `%pre` and `%post`;
- your `%post` is too complicated.

As there are no files at all in your RPM, it will not remove anything when you uninstall it, which is logical. As to the other problems, it would be much better if your `%post` script is a file provided by the RPM, and that another script is provided for cleaning up. Then, your pre, post, preun and postun section would look like:

```
#no %pre

%post
/path/to/install.sh

%preun
# Only if package completely removed!
[ "$1" = "0" ] && /path/to/cleanup.sh

#no %postun
```

But given what you do here, you are probably better off using a tool like Puppet or such.